# Adding secondary via rs.add on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a master and slave on Linux (centOS 7). The `rs.initiate(cfg)` was done, but its shows the below output when trying to add secondary via `rs.add`:

> ```
> genienational:PRIMARY> rs.add("localhost.localdomain:27017")  
> {  
>      "ok" : 0,  
>      "errmsg" : "The hosts test.appraisergenie.com:27017 a  
> nd localhost.localdomain:27017 all map to this node new co  
> nfiguration version 2 for replica set genienational",  
>      "code": 103  
> }  
> genienational:PRIMARY> use local  
> switched to db local
> ```

[image: MongoDB]

How do I resolve?

***Version***: The master is on Enterprise. I think 3.2 and the slave is on 2.6.

Comment: are these all mongo running on same machine? If yes, what are the different ports they are running on?

Comment: I guess adding same port of same machine you are using..

Comment: Please change the port number which should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in your screenshot indicates you are trying to add identical members to your replica set under different names:

```
"The hosts x:27017 and y:27017 all map to this node in new configuration".
```

If you want to configure multiple replica set members on a single machine for testing purposes, all members need to use different ports and/or IP addresses.

> Version: The master is on Enterprise. I think 3.2 and the slave is on 2.6.

Mixed-version replica sets are only supported for consecutive major versions (i.e. 3.2 and 3.0) and expected to be used transiently during a rolling upgrade to a new major version of MongoDB. A mixed replica set with 3.2 and 2.6 members is definitely not supported.